# How can I update changed data on button?

Tags: java, ajax, jsp, spring-mvc

I want to edit data of the user by inputting new value in the textbox such as his first name and show these changes in his profile.
I tried to use Ajax but I don't understand what the url should be in there.
That's my jsp file with edit form and Ajax script:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib  uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("edit").click(function() {
        var firstName = $(request.getParameter("firstname")).val();
        $.ajax({
            url: '',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                firstName: firstName
            }
        });
    });
</script>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>${title}</title>
</head>
<body>
<h4>To edit your information fill the fields, please.</h4>
    <form name='f' action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/j_spring_security_check" method='POST'>
      <table>
         <tr>
            <td>First Name:</td>
            <td><input type='text' name='firstname' id='firstname' value='${firstname}'></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td><input name="edit" type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
         </tr>      
      </table>
    </form>
```

I have update and get methods for the first name in one of the classes:

```
public class UserInfoDAOImpl extends JdbcDaoSupport implements UserInfoDAO {    
    @Autowired
    public UserInfoDAOImpl(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.setDataSource(dataSource);
    }    
//.....other methods

@Override
public void editFirstName(String userName, String fName){
    String sql = "update Users set FirstName = ? where Username = ?";
    Object[] params = new Object[] {fName, userName};
    this.getJdbcTemplate().update(sql, params);
}

@Override
    public String getFirstName(String userName) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
        String sql = "select u.FirstName from Users u where u.Username = ? "; 
        Object[] params = new Object[] { userName };         
        String firstName = (String)getJdbcTemplate().queryForObject(sql, params, String.class);
        return firstName;
    }
}
```

So I don't really get to use these already written methods to update the data and get these changes in user profile.
 I am new to Ajax so I'm glad to get any help.

Answer (score 0):

You are wrong on your JSP, the `j_spring_security_check` is default URL Spring Login.

For updating firstname you must do `@RequestMapping` `@ResponseBody` on your Controller de handle the Ajax Request.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you be more specific about default url? Why it is wrong?

Comment: Are you know Spring Security? please to refer officiel doc [Spring reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#ns-form-and-basic)